# Calling JSON-enabled WCF service with jQuery returns null

Tags: ajax, wcf, json, jquery

I have the following script in my web page to call out to a JSON-enabled WCF service that I have created and am hosting on my web server.  However, the alert displays "null".  When I point to the url in a browser it returns very simple JSON:  `{"city":"Ann Arbor"}`.  Also, when I run the page containing the code below with Fiddler running, I can see the service is hit and the JSON returns.  But still the success function below returns null.  Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks.  -Ned

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://192.168.192.17:8080/Service.svc/class/",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem comes from the fact that you are trying to call a web service using AJAX which is not hosted on the same domain as the calling script and thus you are violating the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). If you want to be able to call `http://192.168.192.17:8080/Service.svc` using AJAX, the calling script needs to be hosted also on `http://192.168.192.17:8080`.

As a possible workaround you could use a server side script acting as bridge hosted on the same domain as the client script or use [JSONP](http://ajaxian.com/archives/jsonp-json-with-padding) if you have control over the web service.

Comment: I ended up hosting it on the same domain which is okay for now.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could define an error function to see what the problem is:

```
$.ajax({
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert(errorThrown)
  },
  //.......
})
```